# C# Dependency Injection frameworks

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which .NET Dependency Injection frameworks are worth looking into?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288/which-net-dependency-injection-frameworks-are-worth-looking-into)

Hi,

As a new kid in the C#/.NET block just moved in from Java neighbourhood, I am looking for options in Dependency Injection/IoC frameworks for .NET/C#.

From [Scott Hanselman's blog post few years ago](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx) I got a fairly long list of DI frameworks, but there was really not enough information to go with beyond the list itself (plus a license and a version number) to make any semi-intelligent choice. Nor have I developed a ghestalt of the relative popularity (and thus the community support available) for any of these. And the list itself dates from 2008, which makes it a bit outdated, so I would like to ask kindly SO community for help on this matter.

**Please list (or vote for) your favourite DI framework, adding a link to framework official website and please be so kind as to provide some reasoning for helping me and others developers like me to make a choice.**

A code sample snippets for declaring and injecting dependencies would be of great help as well.

NB: *Please restrict yourselves to one entry per response please, to keep it simple and objective.*

Comment: This surely have been discussed here at SO previously: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288/which-net-dependency-injection-frameworks-are-worth-looking-into and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581791/how-do-the-major-c-di-ioc-frameworks-compare

Comment: `Please restrict yourselves to one entry per response please, to keep it simple and objective` How can it be objective when everyone vote on their favorite container?

Comment: @jgauffin: by "objective" I meant that the results of such "voting" would very likely reflect relative popularity and mindshare of projects in question... Bun nevermind, as this question was closed as duplicate....

Comment: Yes, but everyone would still vote on their favorite framework. There are no correct answers, just subjective ones.

Comment: @jgauffin it's simple statistics - given enough subjective opinions, trends start to emerge that are as objective as such can be.

Answer (score 2):

I have used Ninject before and got on well with it. There are code samples on the front page of the website.

http://ninject.org/

Edit:
Ninject also supports MVC

Comment: +1. You beat me by 15 seconds, so I'll delete my own answer, but I'd like to add that Ninject also supports ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: :) thanks Aasmund - good point, Ill add to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Of those I have tried, I like [Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff663144.aspx) best by far. Easy to use, and feature rich. A note is that it's not supported if you are developing for Windows Phone 7.

Answer (score 1):

Of the list I've tried Unity, StructureMap and Autofac.

I perfer [StructureMap](http://structuremap.sourceforge.net/), I think it's the most straightforward and easiest to use. *(didn't spend much time with Autofac tho since was just messing in my own time)*

Comment: I prefer structure map too...

Answer (score 0):

You could also use MEF, but be aware that MEF is not only for this purpose. Mostly MEF is a little oversized for normal DI scenarios, but very usefull if you intent to develop a extendible app.