# What is Microsoft Unity?

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I'm looking for some basic examples / explanations of Unity. I have hard time grasping the concept. I do have basic understanding of the Injection pattern as it seems that Unity is tightly related to it. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unity is one of [several DI Containers for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581791/how-do-the-major-c-sharp-di-ioc-frameworks-compare/4583809#4583809). It can be used to compose object graphs, when the types in question follow the [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

The easiest way to do that is to use the **Constructor Injection** pattern:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    private readonly IBar bar;

    public Foo(IBar bar)
    {
        if (bar == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bar");

        this.bar = bar;
    }

    // Use this.bar for something interesting in the class...
}
```

You can now configure Unity in the application's [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx):

```
container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>();
container.RegisterType<IBar, Bar>();
```

The is the *Register* phase of the [Register Resolve Release pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/09/29/TheRegisterResolveReleasePattern.aspx). In the *Resolve* phase the `container` will **Auto-wire** the object graph without further configuration:

```
var foo = container.Resolve<IFoo>();
```

This works automatically because the static structure of the classes involved includes all the information the container needs to compose the object graph.

Comment: To add to Mark's answer (hope he doesn't mind), if you want to learn more about Dependency Injection, there's a really good book called "Dependency Injection in .NET" written by Mark himself. http://www.manning.com/seemann/

Comment: @phill: please don't do that. Mark hates it when people refer to his book :-)

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at:

- [Aspect-Oriented Programming, Interception and Unity 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490353.aspx)
- [Interceptors in Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg535676.aspx)
- [Policy Injection in Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598927.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Check here: [Microsoft Unity 2.0 – April 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff663144.aspx)