# How to define Preprocessor Directive Global in c#

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf

My Question is how to define Preprocessor Directive Global at one place for all C# classes in website.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preprocessor directives across different files in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836501/preprocessor-directives-across-different-files-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me in webconfig:

```
<system.codedom>
<compilers>
  <compiler
    language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
    compilerOptions="/d:custompreprocessor"
    type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, 
    System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
</compilers>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am able to find similar question :
[Preprocessor directives across different files in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836501/preprocessor-directives-across-different-files-in-c-sharp)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;LINQ</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think there is a way to create a global #define.**

You have to create one for each project/assembly in the solution if you need all source code files to know of that #define.