# Access class property at run-time based on dynamic instantiation

Tags: c#

I have the following classes:

```
public Employee : IPerson
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public Manager : IPerson
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

at run-time, I may need to:

```
var person = new Manager();
```

or possibly:

```
var person = new Employee();
```

and then:

```
string name = person.Name;
```

at some point. I'm currently using Activator.CreateInstance(), but was wonder if approaching the problem incorrectly? The type of class is dictated at run-time so I have no advanced noticed.

I was hoping to avoid something like:

```
string externalValue;
var person;

switch (externalValue)
{
  case "Manager":
    person = new Manager();
    break;
  case "Employee":
    person = new Employee();
    break;
}
```

Comment: The question is still not clear for me. Are you trying to avoid the switch? or the magic strings? or you want to avoid instantiating with 'new' keyword?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid all of the above, actually.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Dictionary<string, Func<IPerson>>`, initialize it once and then use to create proper instance:

```
private Dictionary<string, Func<IPerson>> _initializers = new Dictionary<string, Func<IPerson>>() {
    { "Manager", () => new Manager() },
    { "Employee", () => new Employee() }
}
```

```
string externalValue;
var person = _initializers[externalValue]();
```

Comment: OP is trying to avoid magic strings.  This moves the magic string from a switch to a dictionary key.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to create Dependency Injection (DI) system.

> Dependency injection is a software design pattern that allows the removal of hard-coded dependencies and makes it possible to change them, whether at run-time or compile-time

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Rather than re-invent the wheel, I would suggest you look at existing DI systems.  For a good overview, have a look at

[How do the major C# DI/IoC frameworks compare?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581791/how-do-the-major-c-sharp-di-ioc-frameworks-compare/4583809#4583809)